# Can I share variables between get,set,test methods in a custom DSC resource?

Tags: powershell, dsc

I have a simple question. I have been experimenting with Powershell DSC and I have created a custom resource to change the CD drive letter of a client machine.

My current code works, but I would like to see if it can be more efficient. See my code below:

```
enum Ensure 
{ 
    Absent 
   Present 
}

[DscResource()]
class ChangeCDDriveLetter {

[DscProperty(Key)]
[string]$RequiredCDDriveLetter
[DscProperty(NotConfigurable)]
[string]$CurrentCDDriveLetter
[DscProperty(NotConfigurable)]
[string]$CurrentCDVolume

[ChangeCDDriveLetter] Get() {

    $This.CurrentCDDriveLetter = $This.CheckCurrentDriveLetter()
    $This.CurrentCDVolume = $This.CheckCurrentVolume($This.CurrentCDDriveLetter)

    Return $This

}

[Void] Set(){

    $This.CurrentCDDriveLetter = $This.CheckCurrentDriveLetter()
    $This.CurrentCDVolume = $This.CheckCurrentVolume($This.CurrentCDDriveLetter)

    mountvol $This.CurrentCDDriveLetter /d
    mountvol $This.RequiredCDDriveLetter $This.CurrentCDVolume

}

[bool] Test(){

    $This.CurrentCDDriveLetter = $This.CheckCurrentDriveLetter()
    $This.CurrentCDVolume = $This.CheckCurrentVolume($This.CurrentCDDriveLetter)

    Write-Verbose ("Current CD drive letter is: " + $This.CurrentCDDriveLetter)

    if ($This.CurrentCDDriveLetter -ne $This.RequiredCDDriveLetter){

        Write-Verbose ("The CD drive letter should be: " + $This.RequiredCDDriveLetter)
        Write-Verbose ("Setting the CD drive letter to: " + $This.RequiredCDDriveLetter)
        Return $False
    }
    else { 

        Write-Verbose "This is the correct drive letter."
        Return $True 

    }     
}

[string] CheckCurrentDriveLetter(){

    $CurrentDriveLetter = (Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -filter 'DriveType=5').DeviceID
    return $CurrentDriveLetter

}

[string] CheckCurrentVolume($DriveLetter){

    $Volume = (mountvol $DriveLetter /l).Trim()
    Return $Volume

}
```

}

My question is about the following recurring line:

```
$This.CurrentCDDriveLetter = $This.CheckCurrentDriveLetter()
```

As you can see, this information is gathered in the Set,Get and Test methods.

Is it possible to gather this information once and to share this information among the other methods?

So I would gather the information in the Test method, and pass this information to the Set method? I guess doing this will not really have much effect in the current resource, but I would still like to know if it is possible so I can use this in future resources to make them as efficient as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
Bob Smienk

Answer (score 0):

You should not assume that you will have the same instance each time DSC runs you resource.  Therefore, there is **no good way** to have an instance field or instance property persist between executions.

If the value is static to the machine, you can try storing it in a static field, but again should not assume that the order that the methods are called.

Answer (score 0):

What I did, and would do is based on OOP. Call Get() at the beginning of your Test() and Set() methods thus setting the property:

```
[DscResource()]
class ChangeCDDriveLetter {

[DscProperty(Key)]
[string]$RequiredCDDriveLetter
[DscProperty(NotConfigurable)]
[string]$CurrentCDDriveLetter
[DscProperty(NotConfigurable)]
[string]$CurrentCDVolume

[ChangeCDDriveLetter] Get() {

    $This.CurrentCDDriveLetter = $This.CheckCurrentDriveLetter()
    $This.CurrentCDVolume = $This.CheckCurrentVolume($This.CurrentCDDriveLetter)

    Return $This

}

[Void] Set(){

    $This.Get()

    # Replaced by $This.Get()
    # $This.CurrentCDDriveLetter = $This.CheckCurrentDriveLetter()
    # $This.CurrentCDVolume = $This.CheckCurrentVolume($This.CurrentCDDriveLetter)

    mountvol $This.CurrentCDDriveLetter /d
    mountvol $This.RequiredCDDriveLetter $This.CurrentCDVolume

}

[bool] Test(){

    $This.Get()

    # Replaced by $This.Get()
    # $This.CurrentCDDriveLetter = $This.CheckCurrentDriveLetter()
    # $This.CurrentCDVolume = $This.CheckCurrentVolume($This.CurrentCDDriveLetter)

    Write-Verbose ("Current CD drive letter is: " + $This.CurrentCDDriveLetter)

    if ($This.CurrentCDDriveLetter -ne $This.RequiredCDDriveLetter){

        Write-Verbose ("The CD drive letter should be: " + $This.RequiredCDDriveLetter)
        Write-Verbose ("Setting the CD drive letter to: " + $This.RequiredCDDriveLetter)
        Return $False
    }
    else { 

        Write-Verbose "This is the correct drive letter."
        Return $True 

    }     
}
}
```